# use values submitted in a form to publish and subscribe results of a mongodb query in meteor

Tags: javascript, forms, mongodb, meteor, scope

I want a user to be able to type 2 inputs into a form, hit submit, and have the database send back documents with field values that match the values that were typed into the form.

If I hard code values for 'name' and 'code' variables on the last line, I get the right results and everything renders fine.  So I think the problem has to do with how I'm using the variables / variable scope, or something of that nature.

more detailed description below...

1. I am using Meteor.
2. I have a form with 2 input fields, for example, product and brand
3. I want to send a query of the following form:

   `PriceList.find({'name': name, 'brandCode': code});`
4. I have a template that renders based on the results of this query.  This relies on publishing the results of the query:

   if (Meteor.isServer) {
     Meteor.publish('byProductAndBrand', function(){
       var name = product;
       var code = brand;
       return PriceList.find({'name': name, 'brandCode': code});
      });
   }
5. I'm trying to use Meteor.subscribe() to change dynamically based on the form inputs:

   ```
   if (Meteor.isClient) {  
    Template.dataSelectionForm.events({  
       'submit form#addDataSelectionForm': function(event, template){  
         event.preventDefault();  
         product = template.find([name='product_name']).value;  
         brand = template.find([name='brandCode']).value;  
       }  
     });  
     Meteor.subscribe('byProductAndBrand');
   ```

   }
6. Here's the relevant code (duplicates what I wrote above, but may be less annoying to read...)

   PriceList = new Meteor.Collection('PriceList');
     product = 'dummyProduct';
        brand = 'dummyBrandCode';
   if (Meteor.isClient) {
    Template.dataSelectionForm.events({
       'submit form#addDataSelectionForm': function(event, template){
         event.preventDefault();
         product = template.find([name='product_name']).value;
         brand = template.find([name='brandCode']).value;
       }
     });
     Meteor.subscribe('byProductAndBrand');
   }
   if (Meteor.isServer) {
     Meteor.publish('PriceList', function(){
       return PriceList.find();
     });
      Meteor.publish('byProductAndBrand', function(){
       var name = product;
       var code = brand;
       return PriceList.find({'name': name, 'brandCode': code});
      });
   }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass params to `Meteor.subscription` :

```
if(Meteor.isServer){
   Meteor.publish('byProductAndBrand', function(product, brand){
     var name = product;
     var code = brand;
     return PriceList.find({'name': name, 'brandCode': code});
     });
  }
}
if (Meteor.isClient) {  
 Template.dataSelectionForm.events({  
    'submit form#addDataSelectionForm': function(event, template){  
      event.preventDefault();  
      product = template.find([name='product_name']).value;  
      brand = template.find([name='brandCode']).value;
      var instance = Template.instance();
      if(instance.byProductAndBrandHandle != null){
        instance.byProductAndBrandHandle.stop();
      }
      instance.byProductAndBrandHandle = Meteor.subscribe('byProductAndBrand', product ,brand);    
    }  
  });  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you would be better off using dependencies instead of subscriptions.  This makes sense to me in this circumstance because only the one client viewing the page is looking at this particular price list, you are not publishing this price list for multiple users as far as I can tell.

For ex:

In declarations, before if(Meteor.isClient) and if(Meteor.isServer):

var byProductAndBrandDep = new Tracker.Dependency;

Inside of priceList helper:

byProductAndBrandDep.depend();

In "submit form#addDataSelectionForm".events: function(event, templates) {

byProductAndBrandDep.changed();

Then, every time the form is submitted, every helper that has the byProductAndBrandDep.depend() function inside it automatically updates.